# Browser notification not supported

Tags: android, kotlin, browser, notifications

Hi I have simple kotlin webview app for my site
my site have push notification an its working in chrome for windows and chrome for android
but in my app say not supported
this is the image

[Image Fome The App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsAM6.png)

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled", "SdCardPath")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        webframe.loadUrl(getString(R.string.Site_Url))
        webframe.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true//Enable JavaScript
        webframe.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webframe.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
        webframe.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        webframe.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webframe.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
        CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie()
        webframe.restoreState(savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646419/make-web-push-notification-work-using-webview-in-a-native-android-app it seems it is not possible

Comment: oh thank you
but how google chrome can push notification